# How do I message to stackoverflow post moderator

Tags: discussion

I want to message to my question moderator to ask him why he think my post duplicate to another question, but i cant find out where is button or link to send him on his profile

He closed my post, and marked it duplicate but i don't think the "duplicate question" has same problem/answer with mine

Comment: I assume you are talking about [How do I make List<T> include item as variables references (ref item)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448604/how-do-i-make-listt-include-item-as-variables-references-ref-item).  If so then it wasn't closed by a moderator.  It was closed by a user with a high level of reputation in the c# tag.  The solution to your problem is to edit your question to explain why it isn't a duplicate.  the user may have been confused as to what you are looking for (it looks like a dup to me too, so your question may be unclear).

Comment: Just comment on your question with @username.

Comment: Did you read the comment the user left upon closing your question? `What you are asking is effectively to do is to have in your list pointers to pointers (or in the C# vernacular, "references to references"). C# doesn't have that feature. See the marked duplicate for more details. ` That looks fairly... thoughtful. Are you sure it is not a path to a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"... but i don't think the "duplicate question" has same problem/answer with mine."*

Then clarify in your question, why the answers in the marked duplicate don't fit what you're asking for as advised already in the duplicate banner.

You can additionally leave a comment pinging the user that closed your question using @name. They'll be notified.

Comment: On that final paragraph: it's useless to ask "@xyz why r u closing my question?". OP has to actually come up with some pretty good argumentation.

Comment: Yeah. Especially given that the user gave a *very specific* reason why they're dupe-closing.

Comment: @Jongware Sure, I meant something like notifying as _"I have edited my post explaining more why your duplicate doesn't answer my question. Have a look please."_.